module 'keyboard' has no attribute 'is_pressed' - I have trouble using pynput or keyboard libraries - Raspberry Pi 5
Here is some context:
Me and a friend have been making a real life replica of the surveillance drone from Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege. We are now in the process of writing the firmware for controlling its movement.
Two stepper motors are to be controlled independently using some variation of an open-loop control feedback system. For now, to be able to test and develop an acceleration ramp or PWM regime, we need have a python script that can, in real time, control both motors simultaneously to go forward or to backward; think of it like a very dull RC car for now. To achieve real-time control, we have to use pynput and keyboard libraries.

End of context
Problem
To use the pynput and keyboard libraries I have made a virtual environment and am executing my code using the sudo python command. I keep getting an error saying "An error occurred: module 'keyboard' has no attribute 'is_pressed'"; using the following code:
from gpiozero import OutputDevice
from time import sleep
import keyboard

# GPIO pin assignments
DIR1 = 20
STEP1 = 21
DIR2 = 14
STEP2 = 15

# Directions
CW = 1  # Clockwise
CCW = 0  # Counterclockwise

# Steps per revolution
SPR = 200

# Initialize GPIO pins
dir_pin1 = OutputDevice(DIR1)
step_pin1 = OutputDevice(STEP1)
dir_pin2 = OutputDevice(DIR2)
step_pin2 = OutputDevice(STEP2)

# Step count and delay
step_count = SPR
delay = 0.005

def perform_steps(steps, direction1, direction2, delay):
    """
    Perform steps on both motors with given directions and delay.
    """
    dir_pin1.value = direction1
    dir_pin2.value = direction2
    for _ in range(steps):
        step_pin1.on()
        step_pin2.on()
        sleep(delay)
        step_pin1.off()
        step_pin2.off()
        sleep(delay)

def main():
    """
    Main function to continuously handle user input and perform corresponding motor actions.
    """
    try:
        print("Press 'c' for clockwise, 'a' for counterclockwise, or 'q' to quit.")
        while True:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('c'):
                print("Rotating motors CW")
                perform_steps(step_count, CW, CW, delay)
            elif keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
                print("Rotating motors CCW")
                perform_steps(step_count, CCW, CCW, delay)
            elif keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
                print("Exiting the app")
                break
            else:
                sleep(0.1)  # Small delay to prevent excessive CPU usage
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        # Cleanup the pins
        dir_pin1.close()
        step_pin1.close()
        dir_pin2.close()
        step_pin2.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    


have you researched the error?

Solution:
Don't use sudo python in venv; just python.
When making the venv, transfer all system packages to venv as well.
Don't put the library package folder in the same directory as script file.
